# Want to have a layout which arrange in a tabular form

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I am very new to Vaadin. My requirement is like in my page I need to have 4 input component per row. There would be 4 rows like this. I need a layout which will allow me to define number of columns and keep align it.

There should not be any border like we have in table. Please suggest me any suitable layout and how can I customize that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for a [`GridLayout`](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/layout.gridlayout.html), it provides enough flexibility to size your grid 'cells', maintain consistency and set expand ratios for row and columns separately.

The other option for you is to use a [`CustomComponent`](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.customcomponent.html) and in case you are using [Vaadin plugin for eclipse](http://vaadin.com/eclipse) (and I don't have experience with Vaadin on any other IDE) you can use their WYSIWYG editor to translate your requirement to a custom component.

Comment: Thanks for solution. I used gridlayout :)